# Pass jquery as a parameter to an autoexecutable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fount that code

```
(function($) {
    Batch = {
        ...
        ...
})(jQuery);
```

Why pass a reference of JQuery as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to make sure inside that function scope, the `$` variable is referencing jQuery.

Imagine some other vendor library or script on the same page was to use the `$` variable:

```
$ = 42
...

(function() {
    console.log($) //--> 42
})()
```

however, if you pass the global `jQuery` as a parameter like in your snippet:

```
$ = 42
...

(function($) {
    console.log($) //--> ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)} (this is jQuery)
})(jQuery)
```

It will still reference jQuery. This is because inside the function scope, arguments take precedence over outer scope variables with the same name.

to learn more about scopes in javascript, check [this very good article](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch1.md)

Answer (score 0):

It's useful when you want to be sure that $ in your anonymous self-invoking function equals to Jquery and not to another library.